# How do votes get linked between the community user and another user?

Tags: discussion, voting, community-user

Can someone explain in detail how this actually works:

- Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

In a previous question it was mentioned in a comment:

> +3 stuff is "soft" deleted so it's still there for recalculating
>   rep/badges. As Jeff said, "only
>   bad/negative stuff is ever fully
>   deleted" as in not just "soft"
>   deleted, but fully removed from the
>   DB. The downvotes are kept on the
>   community user so the offenders are
>   still punished for their actions

So if something is hard deleted how does allocating the votes to the community user actually punish the offender?

Could someone explain this in database table terms?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. If I downvote one of your posts, that costs you rep. If the Community user downvotes one of your posts, that costs you rep. Why should there be any difference?

Comment: @Cody - But if the post has been permanently deleted and the community user now owns those votes how does the OP still get 'punished' as mentioned in that comment?